# Configure Hibernate 4.1, JPA2 with Spring 3.1.1. to update DB schema from JSR 303 Annotations

Tags: jpa-2.0, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

In my current Hibernate 4.1 + JPA 2 + Spring 3.1.1 configuration the generated `create table` statement doesn't take JSR 303 `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation into consideration.

Class declaration:

```
@Entity
public class MenuItem implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @NotNull    // <--- JSR 303 constraint annotation
    private String description;

    ...
}
```

Generated `create table` statement:

```
create table menu_item (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    description varchar(255),   // <--- should be not null
    price binary(255),
    title varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```

However, if I add JPA `@javax.persistence.Column` annotation, the `create table` statement is generated correctly.

Class declaration:

```
@Entity
public class MenuItem implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @NotNull                 // <--- JSR 303 constraint annotation
    @Column(nullable=false)  // <--- JPA annotation
    private String description;

    ...
}
```

Generated `create table` statement:

```
create table menu_item (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    description varchar(255) not null,   // <--- generated not null
    price binary(255),
    title varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```

Is it possible to configure Hibernate 4.1 + JPA 2 + Spring 3.1.1 to generate DB schema only from JSR 303 annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Only in the case if we widen definition of configure to implement it is possible. JPA 2 itself gives about two pages in specification to Bean validation. Also about DB schema generation from mappings it is not too strict:

> It is permitted, but not required, that DDL generation be supported by
>   an implementation of this specification.

Also I am not aware about Hibernate or Spring providing such a functionality. It is of course bit repetitive to use both @NotNull & nullable=false.